# String.split diferrent behaviour in iex and on phoenix webapi

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

String.split returns an array when is run on iex console. But on Phoenix, it will remove split delimiter from the result:

**Result on iex console**

```
 err = "a,b,c,d"
    res = String.split(err,",")
    output:["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Result on phoenix

```
  keys="a,b,c,d"
  arrkeys1 = String.split(keys,",")
  output:abcd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see in Phoenix is the result of implicit call to `IO.puts/1`:

```
iex(1)> res = String.split(err,",")
#⇒ ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
iex(2)> IO.inspect res                 
#⇒ ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
iex(3)> IO.puts res   
#⇒ abcd
```